# Android Appcompat 21: All my textview are white

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-actionbar-compat

I recently change my actionbar to the new material design. I use the new toolbar widget to show the bars on my activities but all my textviews on the activity are white. I suspect that the "android:textColorPrimary" from my theme change the colors of the textviews but I need this to make the actiobar title be white.

**The toolbar widget:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:theme="@style/Theme.Custom"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>
```

**Theme.Custom:**

```
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Did you check what color '@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark' is?

Comment: Are you saying your TextView's background color is white? and not the Text?

Comment: My bad I didn't clarified it... the color of the text is white. If I dodn't set a custom color on the textviews the default color is white.

Comment: Can you post a photo? What happens if you remove your styles?

Comment: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` already uses white text for the Action Bar but will keep the text in the rest of your app black. So what is it that your theme is trying to do?

Comment: I just tried without defing any style on the toolbar, also define the original Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar and still the textviews are in white color. Here is a [screenshot](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img673/7243/yrLjXK.jpg) inside the black rectangulare are the textviews where supposed to be default black.

Comment: @ianhanniballake With my theme I want to change the color of the overflow icon and the back button to orange. Also without the "android:textColorPrimary" the title of the actionbar is black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found what cause the problem. In `AndroidManifest.xml` when I wanted to define on an activity that I want a theme without `ActionBar` for use the toolbar I used `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` instead of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`